# Asking Better Questions

Tags: discussion, questions, notifications

Jeff Atwood post new article about [Asking Better Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/). Please read and help us enforce the quality of questions.

- if you see a great, thoughtfully asked, well researched question, vote it up — please! Great questions are an art!
- if you see an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended question that you feel was asked in bad faith ... vote it down.
- anything in between that’s salvageable, edit it. You can edit posts if you have 2000 rep or you can suggest an edit and gain 2 rep points if it's approved by someone with over 2000 rep.

Please **use your votes**.

EDIT:

Quoting RobertCartaino from chat:

> Vote, vote, vote. Encourage others to vote, vote, vote. On good content, leave signposts ("If you like this, please vote it up. It's important for the community!")-- in both meta and the main site. Maybe a few meta posts informing the users of the important of that type of participation. You are empowered a lot more than you know.

EDIT2:

**Read: [Vote Early, Vote Often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/) too.**

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: @Tomwij: Can't you edit my post? Or just if it is CW?

Comment: @bigown: he can. So can you.

Comment: @Mr. C:Just to know if it's all right.

Comment: @bigown: It requires me to add one of the four mandatory tags of which none fit to this notice... That's why I flagged instead so that a moderator can adjust the reputation and I guessed the link would be just fine as a first comment. Feel free to correct it yourself and deleting these noise comments...

Comment: @Tomwij: No problem.

Comment: In category # 2, if you've got 500 rep, vote to close.

Comment: Downvoting because this encourages spam and propaganda.

Comment: Can you stop spamming this question all over Programmers.SE? A meta topic with the `[featured]` tag will suffice. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/389?tab=activity#tab-top

Comment: To be fair to @bigown, I think that the problem probably won't be addressed on meta as the amount of people who visit and participate on meta are few and far between compare to the users of the main site, so it's fair to try and do something there. Whether adding lots of comments is the way, I'm not sure - but that's preferable to just posting something on meta.

Comment: @TheLQ: Can you read this "question" before to comment?

Comment: Just wanted to return to this post and note that the question talks about voting, not closing. We seem to have gotten into a closefest based on the six guidelines for subjective questions and I still have yet to be convinced that these guidelines have come from this community, rather than from Jeff. I'm all for upvoting and downvoting and try to use my votes regularly, but closing is another matter entirely, particularly closing for the six subjective guidelines reason, as a) They are guidelines, not laws and b) they were not hashed out by this community.

Comment: By the way, I am not for anarchy and I do vote to close questions, but not for the six subjective guidelines reason. I think the existing reasons suffice.

Comment: @TheLQ: If you see spam in comments, flag it.

Comment: I thought the limit for editing was 2,000 rep?

Comment: 1: Was there a question here?

Comment: @JimG Posts on meta don't always have to be questions.

Comment: @Louis The limit is 600 but the OP has to approve the edit.

Answer (score 2):

As a corollary to this, many might not be aware down-voting on questions is now free. There's never been a better time to liberally use your votes to [optimize the site for pearls, not sand](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).